# Stream playback from Wowza has audio crackling on Flash player

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, video-streaming, wowza, cracking

I have a custom Flash video player that uses the NetConnection and NetStream classes to stream mp4 files from a Wowza server.
Lately the playback has been having audio problems. The sound is crackled and in some cases may cause the Flash player to crash. This is not consistent between files. Meaning that a file that was played once with bad audio could be fine 5 minutes later when played again from a new instance of the player , but 5 minutes later have the same problem.

My thought direct me to thinking this was an encoding problem, but that wouldn't explain how one second the playback is fine, and once refreshed messes up again.

I should note that the Wowza server does not stream the entire file but only a portion of it based on various parameters it gets.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the audio crackle when you use a standard player and/or a different client machine?  My first thought is that this is a custom player or client sound processing issue.

If this reproduces on any player or client, then we should also troubleshoot the server.  If you end up thinking it might be server-related, please post a message on the Wowza forum:  http://www.wowza.com/forums/forum.php.